# Error at ARPA model training with SRILM

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx, sphinx4, language-model, srilm

I have followed [this](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm) tutorial.

After I run this code:

```
ngram-count -kndiscount -interpolate -text train-text.txt -lm your.lm
```

It gives me this error:

> "One of modified KneserNey discounts is negative error in discount
>   estimator for order 2."

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 possibilities that `-kndiscount` is giving you an error:

1. Your `dataset` is small.
2. Your phrases in the `dataset` are small which is a hurdle for a proper `ngram` training using `kndiscount`.

The solution could be:

1. Create a bigger `dataset`.
2. Use other discount techniques.

For reference have a look at this thread:
https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/97ae0e5c/#a760